# HTML select change not working for jQuery function

Tags: jquery, html

I created a pagination for a table in a HTML page using jQuery. Following code is working.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#transactionsTable').after('<ul id="nav" class="pagination"></ul>');
      var rowsShown = 10;
      var rowsTotal = $('#transactionsTable tbody tr').length;
      var numPages = rowsTotal/rowsShown;
      for(i = 0;i < numPages;i++) {
          var pageNum = i + 1;
          $('#nav').append('<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" rel="'+i+'">'+pageNum+'</a></li> ');
      }
      $('#transactionsTable tbody tr').hide();
      $('#transactionsTable tbody tr').slice(0, rowsShown).show();
      $('#nav a:first').addClass('active');
      $('#nav a').bind('click', function(){

          $('#nav a').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
          var currPage = $(this).attr('rel');
          var startItem = currPage * rowsShown;
          var endItem = startItem + rowsShown;
          $('#transactionsTable tbody tr').css('opacity','0.0').hide().slice(startItem, endItem).
          css('display','table-row').animate({opacity:1}, 300);
      });
  });
```

It shows 10 rows of the table per page and the pagination bar. Now I want to set the number of rows show per page dynamic. So I created a `<select>` with several `<option> s` like 10, 25, 50, 100

```
<select id="pagingCount" class="">
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="25">25</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="100">100</option>
        </select>
```

and change the code as follows

```
var rowsShown = $('#pagingCount').val();
```

but it is not working. Always it shows 10 rows per page. How can I fix this?

Comment: why are you not using datatable using jquery i just write simple link http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/ follow this

Comment: I'm not allowed to use any external script other than jQuery.js

Comment: try using `$('#pagingCount option').val();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to change the value of `rowsShown` in your code block.

```
function showRows(rowsShown){
      $('#transactionsTable').after('<ul id="nav" class="pagination"></ul>');
      var rowsTotal = $('#transactionsTable tbody tr').length;
      var numPages = rowsTotal/rowsShown;
      for(i = 0;i < numPages;i++) {
          var pageNum = i + 1;
          $('#nav').append('<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" rel="'+i+'">'+pageNum+'</a></li> ');
      }
      $('#transactionsTable tbody tr').hide();
      $('#transactionsTable tbody tr').slice(0, rowsShown).show();
      $('#nav a:first').addClass('active');
      $('#nav a').bind('click', function(){

          $('#nav a').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
          var currPage = $(this).attr('rel');
          var startItem = currPage * rowsShown;
          var endItem = startItem + rowsShown;
          $('#transactionsTable tbody tr').css('opacity','0.0').hide().slice(startItem, endItem).
          css('display','table-row').animate({opacity:1}, 300);
      });

}
  $(document).ready(function(){
   showRows(10);
  });

$("#pagingCount").on("change", function(e){
  showRows(e.target.value);
});
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: When I tried to change the value from select, page will keep the previous pagination bar as well. Ex. At the start, there are 5 pages for 10 per page. After change it to 25 per page, it shows  2 pages with previous 5 pages so total 7 pages

Comment: If you need to remove previous pages, you can simply use `.remove()` method of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try use `:selected` to get the current value.

`var rowsShown = $('#pagingCount option:selected').val();`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve selected value by using this code.

Its simple in JQuery to get selected value.

```
var rowsShown= $('#pagingCount').find(":selected").text();
```